# Database unit testing - How to mock the time within a procedure

Tags: unit-testing, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, python-unittest

I have a TSQL procedure in an Azure Database Instance. The procedure has logic that determines the state of an ETL process and **is sensitive to the current time** to determine whether an event is within bound or not within bound. This procedure has complex behaviour and **is a core requirement**.

I must validate the behaviour of the procedure. I am writing unit tests in Python, I am using `unittest` to manage tests and `pyodbc` to make the calls to the database. These unit tests must validate the behaviour of the procedure irrespective of the time that the procedure is called. **I need the database to behave as if it is a certain time like '05:30:00' for example**.

I am familiar with the concept of mocking objects to run tests at any time and to remove external dependencies. I do not think this applies to Microsoft databases, more like a REST API for example. Another consideration is that **I would not want to target a copy of the object** that I want to test as the copy might not be the same as the original.

**The only solutions that come to mind (*bad solutions*) are:**

- Implement a variable in the procedure to hold `DATETIME` and override this using a parameter with a `DEFAULT` specification instead of `GETDATE()`.
- Use some conditional logic that is only executed if the session was authenticated by the application account that runs the tests, using a default value for the time.

**Outcomes of 1 would be;**

- All calls to the procedure would need to be updated
- A parameter that *shouldn't be there* would now be included
- Risk of calling the procedure with the wrong arguments would be increased and could cause havoc *silently*

**Outcomes of 2 would be;**

- Testing is dependent on the user account not changing and if we segregate responsibility for security implementation and that person is not available we would be temporarily stuck
- Slower procedure
- Reduced readability

Both of these options are awful. Has anybody been able to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure **will not** access time with `GETDATE()` from within the procedure. The `DATETIME` will be supplied to a **procedure parameter provided by an outer scope**.

This will require a bit of refactoring but will mean that the procedure is then unit testable. Wish I had thought of it more quickly :/